# How to stop Python Pandas from converting specific column from int to float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

trying to out put a dataframe into txt file (for a feed). a few specific columns are getting automatically converted into float instead of int as intented.

how can i specific those columns to use int as dtype?
i tried to output the whole dataframd as string and that did not work.

the columns i would like to specify are named [CID1] and [CID2]

```sql
    data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
    data = data.astype(str)
    data.to_csv('data_feed_feed.txt', sep ='\t',index=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried data["CID1"] = data["CID1"].astype(int)

Comment: Specific to your title, you can't. All rows within a column must be the same data type

Comment: i am trying to convert the whole column (all rows) for both CID1 and CID2 into int.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, you turn all of your data to strings just before export.

Thus, you either need to turn some cols back to desired type, such as:

```
data["CID1"] = data["CID1"].astype(int)
```

or not convert them in the first place.

It is not clear from what you provided why you'd have issues with ints being converted to floats.

this post provides heaps of info:
[stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/9249533](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/9249533)